# how to match continuous string input to passage in javascript, while showing mistakes?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

Hey guys I am working on an application and so far its going well but while working on a recent features i am a little stuck.
Here is my problem:
using java script I am getting continuous user speech input and transcribing it. While I am getting this speech input i want to be able to identify and highlight the text on the screen that is being read. I want to highlight mistakes (words spoken that don't match) and I want to highlight all the content that is going correct.
I am not asking for someone to code this for me, i just want to be pointed in the right direction.

A similar implementation you have probably seen is in online typing games. where you try to type parts of a passage as fast as possible and it highlights the ones you are getting right and the ones that you are getting wrong.

Any help is appreciates, libraries, algorithms, methods, or terms I should search. Thank you !

Comment: show us what code you have so far

Comment: its too long, i will just explain it for clarity. I am using bing speech to text so I get continuous results from recognizer.recognized = function(s, e), then input it in to a Boyer MooreHorspool(string matching alg) implementation that i made. It finds the corresponding location of the text and highlights it. This doesn't work well since the speech has to match perfectly with the content on the page.

Comment: Boyer MooresHorspool does not work if any part of the substring does not match in the content. I want to be able to continuously go along the passage as the user reads and show matches and mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you indexing the text at all? Do you know the text in advance? If you created an in memory graph database using each word in the text, you could search edges to find 'weighted' hits. It's ambitious, but there's an article here:

https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/07/07/mining-and-searching-text-with-graph-databases.html

If you want to go dirt simple and follow your typing game analogy:

- In the typing game an event is fired each input (keypress).
- The key pressed is compared to the expected one.
- If it is not correct it is flagged as wrong.
- There is usually no way to go back and correct the mistakes.
- The user has to type the next expected letter correctly to
  get things rolling correctly again.

You could do the same thing.

- Underline the next expected word.
- Each word (whitespace) is an event.
- Match the text to speech word to the expected word.
- If it is not right, flag it as wrong, strike it out.
- The user has to say the next underlined word correctly to start things going smoothly again.
- You could allow the user to back space the expected word so he/she could start over where they wanted to.

This will have some hiccups, as all things speech to text do, but it will work like your typing game and be simple to implement.

Comment: thank you, ill take a look. Although its a very interesting article and im going to go through it, quick look it looks like its over kill for what i asked.